Query overlapping date periods
Each line represents a patient taking two drugs.



RX_START_DATE
RX_END_DATE
OTHER_RX_START_DATE
OTHER_RX_END_DATE




05/05/2023
07/05/2023
06/05/2023
08/05/2023


01/03/2023
03/03/2023
02/03/2024
04/03/2024



I need the code to find the latest start date and the earliest end date to make sure that the date range is for when the patient is taking a combination.
In the table example above for the first row, I would want the COMBO_START_DATE = 06/05/2023 and the COMBO_END_DATE = 07/05/2023 because this would be when they would overlap.
I'm not really sure how to do this. I was going to write a stored procedure, but I'm not sure how if-then statements work in T-SQL, or how I would use a procedure to add an extra column.

What version of SQL Server? Recent versions have a pair of new functions that will change the best option for you.

Also: we only have an example for the first row. What do you want for the second row? Just show the later start/ends, even if though they don't overlap? Filter out the row?

Are the the end dates inclusive or exclusive? In other words, if RX_END_DATE= OTHER_RX_START_DATE, does this represent a 1 day overlap or no overlap.

Please add few more different sample data.


I'm not really sure how to do this. I was going to write a stored procedure, but I'm not sure how if-then statements work in T-SQL, or how I would use a procedure to add an extra column.

It's not clear what you want the result to be. Do you want to actually change the underlying data? That would be... unusual. It's also not clear what you want to do with the second row, which does not overlap.
But, based on what we have, the common way to do this leaves the data alone, and just runs an SQL SELECT query as needed to show the result set. You might formalize this with a View or stored procedure, but you don't need to; you can just run queries.
In this case, assuming these are actually date columns or if they are strings they are at least well-formatted, the query might look like this (but requires at least SQL Server 2022):
SELECT LEAST(RX_Start_Date, Other_RX_Start_Date) COMBO_START_DATE
      ,GREATEST(RX_End_Date, Other_RX_End_Date)  COMBO_END_DATE
FROM [MyTable]

As we can see, this is waaaay simpler than other options.
And if you want to exclude the 2nd row, which does not overlap, you might use a WHERE clause:
SELECT LEAST(RX_Start_Date, Other_RX_Start_Date) COMBO_START_DATE
      ,GREATEST(RX_End_Date, Other_RX_End_Date)  COMBO_END_DATE
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE RX_START_DATE < OTHER_RX_END_DATE AND RX_END_DATE > OTHER_RX_START_DATE

But in my experience you'll find the opposite is often better: there is as much or more value in surfacing rows that are out of compliance, so someone can take action to correct things:
SELECT LEAST(RX_Start_Date, Other_RX_Start_Date) COMBO_START_DATE
      ,GREATEST(RX_End_Date, Other_RX_End_Date)  COMBO_END_DATE
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE RX_START_DATE >= OTHER_RX_END_DATE OR RX_END_DATE <= OTHER_RX_START_DATE

Finally, let's say this really about changing the underlying data... that is, you want to DELETE invalid rows. In that case, the query would look like this:
DELETE
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE RX_START_DATE >= OTHER_RX_END_DATE OR RX_END_DATE <= OTHER_RX_START_DATE

Note my WHERE conditional expressions do NOT use the LEAST() or GREATEST() methods, because they would prevent any index for these columns from being useful for this query.

I believe the above has the usage of LEAST() and GREATEST() reversed. If the resulting combo dates are to represent the overlap, then you would want GREATEST(RX_Start_Date, Other_RX_Start_Date) AS COMBO_START_DATE and LEAST(RX_End_Date, Other_RX_End_Date) AS COMBO_END_DATE. Also worth noting: The use of strict inequalities (> and <) or non-strict inequalities (>= and <=) depends on whether or not the end date is inclusive or exclusive. In other words, does end-date1 = start-date2 represent a 1 day overlap or no overlap.

Query to find overlap dates if they exist. I modified the solution from here and applied it to your example. I think CASE works better then IF for this problem.
SELECT *, 
  
      CASE WHEN RX_START_DATE < OTHER_RX_START_DATE 
      THEN  OTHER_RX_START_DATE  
      ELSE  RX_START_DATE 
      END as COMBO_START_DATE,
  
      CASE WHEN RX_END_DATE > OTHER_RX_END_DATE 
      THEN  OTHER_RX_END_DATE  
      ELSE  RX_END_DATE 
      END as COMBO_END_DATE
FROM Example
WHERE 
  --(StartA <= EndB) and (EndA >= StartB)
  (RX_START_DATE <= OTHER_RX_END_DATE) AND  (RX_END_DATE >= OTHER_RX_START_DATE)

fiddle



RX_START_DATE
RX_END_DATE
OTHER_RX_START_DATE
OTHER_RX_END_DATE
COMBO_START_DATE
COMBO_END_DATE




2023-05-05
2023-07-05
2023-06-05
2023-08-05
2023-06-05
2023-07-05



